# Change directories in Python, not working

Tags: python

I am trying hard to implement this function:

**change the directories if they are present in FTP and if not, create them and change directories to it**.

```
def directory_exists(self, directory_name):
        if directory_name in ftp.nlst():
            self.change_directory(directory_name)
        else:
            self.make_directory(directory_name) and self.change_directory(directory_name)
```

**Function calls:**

```
def make_directory(self, directory):
        if ftp.mkd(directory):
            self.log_message("Directory {0} created successfully".format(directory))
            return True
        else:
            self.log_message("Failed creating directory")
            return False

def change_directory(self, directory):
        if ftp.cwd(directory):
            self.log_message("Current Directory is now {0}".format(ftp.pwd()))
        else:
            self.log_message("Can't change Directory")
```

This code currently works if any new directory is given as the `parameter` and if the existing directory is given, this traceback comes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ajay/PycharmProjects/database/config.py", line 17, in <module>
    ftp_obj.directory_exists(directory)
  File "C:\Users\Ajay\PycharmProjects\database\ftp.py", line 51, in directory_exists
    self.make_directory(directory_name) and self.change_directory(directory_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ajay\PycharmProjects\database\ftp.py", line 34, in make_directory
    if ftp.mkd(directory):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 568, in mkd
    resp = self.sendcmd('MKD ' + dirname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 244, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 219, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Can't create directory: File exists
```

**My Code Function call logic:**

```
directory = '/new'
ftp_obj.directory_exists(directory)
```

Comment: That is not how `and` works...

Comment: @goncalopp When the new directory **which is not present in server** is given, it makes that directory and cd's into it successfully.

Comment: @goncalopp -- the ftplib docs say that cwd changes the current directory on the server: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.cwd

Comment: Are you sure that `ftp.nlst()` returns a list that is in the same format as `directory_name`?  For instance might one of them be an absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by little trick.

```
def directory_exists(self, directory_name):
        new_dir_name = directory_name.strip("/")
        if new_dir_name in ftp.nlst():
            self.change_directory(directory_name)
        else:
            self.make_directory(directory_name)
            self.change_directory(directory_name)
```

Now, Everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `ftp.nlst` returns the directory names in a format that does not exactly match the format you are using ('newdir' vs. './newdir' vs. '/full/path/newdir'). However, `ftp.mkd` throws an exception, rather than returning False, when you try to create a directory that already exists. With this in mind, you could just change `directory_exists` to always try to create the directory, and then chdir regardless of whether it succeeds:

```
def directory_exists(self, directory_name):
    try:
        ftp.mkd(directory_name)
        self.log_message("Directory {0} created successfully".format(directory))
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        pass #you could check for other errors also
    self.change_directory(directory_name)
```